# Trendline Equation Evaluation Variable Values not Updating in Loop

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing a program that will take two trend lines that cross and keep evaluating them until a point that is acceptably close to the crossing is found.

I have got to the point where I have the trendlines, formatted how I like, and I've replaced the x's with a variable (one column of an array). When I start my loop, where there are 100 inputs, the lowest of which will be my "point", the variable doesn't update to the new value, or step, before the trendline equations are evaluated.

Here's the relevant section of my code, where tl1eq and tl2eq are my trendline equation strings:

```
tl1eq = Replace(tl1eq, "y =", "")
tl1eq = Replace(tl1eq, "x2", "x^2")
tl1eq = Replace(tl1eq, "x", " * " & flhd(i, 1) & " ")

tl2eq = Replace(tl2eq, "y =", "")
tl2eq = Replace(tl2eq, "x6", "x^6")
tl2eq = Replace(tl2eq, "x5", "x^5")
tl2eq = Replace(tl2eq, "x4", "x^4")
tl2eq = Replace(tl2eq, "x3", "x^3")
tl2eq = Replace(tl2eq, "x2", "x^2")
tl2eq = Replace(tl2eq, "x", " * " & flhd(i, 1) & " ")

'create an step amount between low and high flows, with 100 steps
x = (hflow - lflow) / 100

'fill array with step values and summation of curve equations
For i = 1 To 100
    flhd(i, 1) = lflow + (x * i)
    flhd(i, 2) = Abs(Evaluate(tl1eq) - Evaluate(tl2eq))
    MsgBox (flhd(i, 1) & " " & tl1eq & " " & Evaluate(tl1eq) & " " & tl2eq & " " & Evaluate(tl2eq))
Next i
```

flhd(i, 1) doesn't update in the strings when evaluating, but when in the msgbox it shows it as the correct value.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to do your replacement of `x` within the loop.  Right now you're evaluating the same two equations 100 times.  It would help your question to show the original values of `tl1eq` and `tl2eq` and provide sample inputs for `hflow` and `lflow`

Comment: If I replace x in the loop, won't I get an error on the second loop when x has already been replaced?
tl1eq and tl2eq are dynamic but are defined as ax2 + bx + c and dx6 + ex5..., just second and 6th order polynomials
Sample inputs are just any two numbers where lflow is a lower number and hflow is a higher number. The user is supposed to interpret the chart and provide two numbers between which the trendlines cross.

Comment: It's difficult to test without concrete examples - I would try out the fix myself but would like not to waste time figuring out sample equations and values.  As to the second loop - you wouldn't just move those two lines inside the loop: create two more strings which can hold the modified equations resulting from the x replacements: don't modify tl1eq and tl2eq beyond the `x2` replacement steps.

Comment: Ahh, it took a few tries, but that worked. Thanks so much!